# python web scraping of a dynamically loading page

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let's say i want to scrape this page: https://twitter.com/nfl

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = 'https://twitter.com/nfl'
r = requests.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup
```

The more i scroll down on the page, the more results show up. But this above request only gives me the initial load. How do i get all the information of the page as if I were to manually scroll down?

Comment: Hi, I am in similar situation as yours, my recommendation is to learn a little bit of js ( that is what I am doing right now). You can actually call the js file with appropriate parameters to make it directly output the data to a file (json most likely). But since I am learning it now, I can't provide a better solution. Correct me if I am wrong. The case I am working on is http://stocktwits.com/symbol/aapl . I hope it will you a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution is to use [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/).

There are several python twitter API clients, for example:

- [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)
- [twitter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter)
- [python-twitter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/1.3.1)

Comment: good suggestion. I'll probably give that a shot if there is no good generic solution.

Comment: @jason_cant_code well, this is definitely the way to go if you need the data from twitter.

Comment: Definitely if you can use a API, forget scraping. This is your solution.

Answer (score 4):

First parse the `data-max-id="451819302057164799"` value from the html source.

Then using the id `451819302057164799` construct an url like below:

`https://twitter.com/i/profiles/show/nfl/timeline?include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&max_id=451819302057164799`

Now get the html source of the link and parse using `simplejson` or any other json library.

Remember, the next page load(when you scroll down) is available from the value `"max_id":"451369755908530175"` in that json.

Comment: `https://twitter.com/i/profiles/show/nfl/timeline?include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&max_id=451819302057164799` is this a generic solution for all twitter pages? how do you know how to construct that specific url?

Comment: @jason_cant_code can be. I didn't check. May be the `nfl` is the key for different pages.

Comment: i don't think this works. I'm getting a much shorter page than expected.

Comment: Use requests session to ensure that you keep alive your session in every GET

Answer (score 1):

If the content is dynamically added with javascript, your best chance is to use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to control a headless browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), use the selenium webdriver to simulate the scrolldown, add a wait for the new content to load, and only then extract the html and feed it to your BS parser.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583560/selenium-retrieve-data-that-loads-while-scrolling-down for scrolling down

Comment: I'll try this if there is no better solution

Comment: Yes, Selenium is always an option.... but IMO is not the best one. I preffer to figure out the http traffic between browser and server and simulate it using requests, urllib or whatever.... much faster than Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generated content, the data is usually in **json** format. So we have to inspect the page, go to network option and find the link which will give us the data/response on the fly.
For example : The page - https://techolution.app.param.ai/jobs/ the data is generated dynamically. For that I got this link - https://techolution.app.param.ai/api/career/get_job/?query=&locations=&category=&job_types=

After that the web scraping becomes a bit easy and I have done that in **python** using **Anaconda** Navigator. Here is the **github** link for that - https://github.com/piperaprince01/Webscraping_python/blob/master/WebScraping.ipynb

If you can make any changes to make it better then feel free to do so.
Thank You.